# Defining Browser with ScenarioContext in SpecFlow/C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

Could anyone help me understand how to define the browser to use using ScenarioContext? I'm fairly new to C#/SpecFlow and have found some examples of how to set up my project, but I'm not clear how these can be used to define whether I want to use IE, Chrome etc, and to easily switch between them.

I currently have a web browser cs file which gets called first, as below:

```
public static IWebDriver Current
{
    [BeforeScenario]
    get
    {
        if (!ScenarioContext.Current.ContainsKey("browser"))
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current["browser"] = new ChromeDriver(@"c:\");
        }
        return (IWebDriver)ScenarioContext.Current["browser"];
    }
}
```

I then have a feature file, which points to the below .cs  stepdef implementation:

```
[Given(@"I navigate to the papers home page using (.*)")]
public void GivenINavigateToThePapersHomePage(string specificBrowser)
{
    var papersDashboard = new PapersDashboard(TemplateProject2.WebBrowser.Current);
    papersDashboard.goToPage();
}
```

What I want to know is how to pass in a browser variable from the feature file level.

Is it possible to set up a key in the feature file where I state browser=IE or browser=chrome, and for this to be referenced in the WebBrowser cs file? Or an I thinking about the architecture wrong here? Thanks in advance, Mike

Driver is initialised in page object page, as below:

```
private IWebDriver driver;
public PapersDashboard(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
{   
this.driver = TemplateProject2.WebBrowser.Current;
PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);}
```

Comment: When you are initializing the Selenium Webdriver you can use the Current property of the WebBrowser to select the correct Webdriver. Where do you initialize the webdriver?

Comment: Hi Koen, so In my page object for the landing page. I have put it in original post at bottom as code wasnt formatting correctly in the 'reply' box.
My step definition (outlined above) then points to this page object. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this for the initialisation of the webdriver:

```
   IWebDriver driver;
   if (TemplateProject2.WebBrowser.Current == "Firefox")
   {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   } 
   else if (TemplateProject2.WebBrowser.Current == "Chrome") {
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
   }
   else {
      driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
   }
```